# Why is covariant basis positive-definite?

Tags: tensors

I'm studying a (tensor calculus) book that says:

> Any covariant basis, interpreted as a matrix, is positive-definite.

But I have stumbled upon seeing this claim. Let's assume a non-trivial vector $\mathrm{V} := V^{i}\mathrm{Z}_{i}=V^{j}\mathrm{Z}_{j}$. We know that $\mathrm{V}\cdot\mathrm{V}>0$. So, one may say $V^{i}(\mathrm{Z}_{i}\cdot \mathrm{Z}_{j}) V^{j}>0$. In matrix notation, we get $\mathrm{V}^{T}(\mathrm{Z}_{i}\cdot \mathrm{Z}_{j})\mathrm{V}>0$. This inequality asserts that the covariant metric tensor $Z_{ij}$ is positive-definite. But, why can one include the same about $\mathrm{Z}_{i}$ and $\mathrm{Z}_{j}$, as well?

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @user1046533: "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces" by Grinfeld

Comment: Whut, what does it mean to interpret basis as a matrix?

Comment: @Buraian: It is in the page 57 of the cited book above.

Comment: It would be helpful to make your question self-contained by adding definitions from the book.

Comment: @User . You have shown that the matrix $Z_{ij}=(Z_i\cdot Z_j)$ is positive definite. What do yo mean by "one can include the same about $Z_i$ and $Z_j$ as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

The following is is totally trivial and has not even anything to do with tensor calculus. For any vector $v=(v^1,...,v^n)$ the matrix
$$
v\otimes v=\begin{pmatrix}v^1v^1&...&v^1v^n\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\v^nv^1&...&v^nv^n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v^1&0&...&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\v^n&0&...&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}v^1&...&v^n\\0&\dots&0\\0&...&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
is positive semi definite because it is a Cholesky desomposition.